# Get SUM of sales for multiple years in columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to get something like this:

```
*Customer    *2009     *2010    *
|------------|---------|--------|
|Peter       |120      |240     |
|Johe        |455      |550     |
```

My first approach to the query was this:

```
Select c.name, sum(o2009.price), sum(o2010.price) from customer c
join orders o2009 on (o2009.customerId = c.id AND o2009.year = 2009)
join orders o2010 on (o2010.customerId = c.id AND o2010.year = 2010)
group by c.id
```

Unfortunately this is completely wrong. I guess I could run 2 queries and then build a union, but maybe there is something simpler?

Comment: We have to guess your table structures, that's never good. But one table per year looks like a conception error to me.

Comment: it's not one table per year, he's just doing naming.

Comment: @lijie : I must be tired, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Hmm looks like mysql does not have pivot - in sql server, this is a breeze using the pivot keyword!

Comment: Pivot would be nice, yes. Sorry for not providing the table structure, it's just a basic order and customer table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modifying one of the answers to get customers with no orders -

```
Select c.name, 
   Sum(Case When o.year == 2008 Then price Else 0 End) cy2008,
   Sum(Case When o.year == 2009 Then price Else 0 End) cy2009,
   Sum(Case When o.year == 2010 Then price Else 0 End) cy2010
From Customers c left outer join 
     Orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
Group By c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Sub-query is not advisable,
but should work the trick

such as

```
SELECT 
  c.name, 
 (
   SELECT 
     ISNULL(SUM(o2009.price), 0)
   FROM orders as o2009
   WHERE 
     o2009.year=2009 AND o2009.customerId=c.id
 ) as sum_2009,
 (
   SELECT 
     IFNULL(SUM(o2010.price), 0)
   FROM orders as o2010
   WHERE 
     o2009.year=2010 AND o2010.customerId=c.id
 ) as sum_2010
 FROM customer c
```

**Always check the query cost**

Comment: this might turn out to be really ugly in terms of performance for a db with large number of customers..

Comment: Thanks for the comment, in our case we don't really care, as we only run that once in a while.

Comment: @Remy - I think is fair for you to post both query cost for comparison, and always use better and optimized query.

Answer (score 0):

if you do `select c.name, o.year, sum(o.price) from customer as c inner join orders as o on o.customerId = c.id group by c.id, o.year`, you get something usable, but not in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select c.name, 
   Sum(Case When o2008.year == 2009 Then price Else 0 End) cy2008,
   Sum(Case When o2009.year == 2009 Then price Else 0 End) cy2009,
   Sum(Case When o2010.year == 2009 Then price Else 0 End) cy2010
From Orders o
Group By`enter code here` c.Name
```

Comment: this will not return for customer that did not place any orders

Comment: Just do a left join to the customers