# mysql conditional summation

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, sum

i'm trying to do age analysis on some data and need to do a conditional summation i.e my table is :

```
ID | Date    | Amount |
===+=========+========+    
1  | 1/1/10  | 100    |
2  | 1/2/10  | 100    |
3  | 1/5/10  | 100    |
4  | 15/5/10 | 100    |
5  | 20/5/10 | 100    |
```

Say the date today is 1/6/10 I'd like to sum the amount depending on their age as used in age analysis. i.e i'd like this out

```
Age        | Total
===========+======
<30 days   | 300
30-60 days | 0
60-90 days | 0
90 days+   | 200
```

Essentially its a conditional summation so I want to sum all the values (<30 days, then 30-60 days, then 60-90 days, then 90days+)

Comment: There is something similar to what you want to do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278570/get-sum-of-sales-for-multiple-years-in-columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select case 
           when datediff(now(), date) >= 90 then '90 days+'
           when datediff(now(), date) >= 60 and datediff(now(), date) < 90 then '60-90 days'
           when datediff(now(), date) >= 30 and datediff(now(), date) < 60 then '30-60 days'
           else '< 30 days'
       end case f,
       sum(amount)
  from your_table
 group by f;
```